# Django - Listing first model field values in second model createView form field for logged in user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to add a transaction (2nd model) for a specific account (1st model) based on the logged in user, either by listing the available account in the transaction `creatView`, or by clicking on the account name on the rendered HTML page.

```py
class Account(models.Model):
      account_holder_name = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field="username",on_delete=models.CASCADE)                    
      # other fields


class Transaction(models.Model):
      account = models.ForeignKey(Account,to_field="account_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)             
      # other fields
```

I can add account successfully using below `form_valid` function in `CreateView`:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    userName = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
    form.instance.account_holder_name = userName
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

And also created `ListView` for accounts related to login user:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    return Account.objects.filter(account_holder_name=self.request.user.username)
```

Rendering it in HTML by looping object list showing available accounts for the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Transaction(genric.creatView):  
        user=Account.objects.filter(account_holder_name=self.request.user.username)
        tran_create=Transaction.object.create(account_name=user,**Kwargs)
        tran_create.save()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?